# Update vlookup table array

Tags: vlookup

Suppose I have the following vlookup command:

`=VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!S2,'Sheet2'!$B$138:$C$145,2,FALSE)`

When I drag the vlookup to the right I want it to update to

`=VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!S2,'Sheet2'!$B$146:$C$153,2,FALSE)`

In other words, I want the letters B and C fixed but the numbers to increment by 8. How would I do this?

Comment: I think you should organise  your data another way so  you can select an entire column within the vlookup.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your answer is always in column C and your lookup value in column A. If this is the case use `INDEX` `MATCH`

```
=INDEX ( C:C , MATCH ( 'Sheet1'!S2 , 'Sheet2'!$B:$C , 0 ))
```

I've made a few assumptions. Drop a pic of your tables and I can amend it if you can't work out which bits to change

Answer (score -1):

That may be possible using some long if-then-else logic or macro but it seems an odd thing to do.  The numbers represent rows so if you are incrementing them across columns I wonder whether you need to transpose your data and/or use HLOOKUP instead.  There is probably a better way to achieve what you want but it is difficult to answer from the question as provided.